# Derivative bounded by the original function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f \in C^1[0, \infty]$ with $f(0)=0$. Suppose $\exists m >0$ s.t. $$0 \leq f'(x)\leq m f(x) \qquad \forall x \geq 0$$
Prove that $f=0$.

$\\$

To start we note that $f$ is non-decreasing so $f\geq 0$ on the other hand
$$f(x)=\int_0^x f'(t) dt \leq m \int_0^x f(t) dt \leq m x f(x)$$

Thus $(1-mx) f(x) \leq 0$ for any $x\geq 0$ hence $f=0$ on $[0,\frac{1}{m}]$. How to conclude the proof? I guess one needs to use $f \in C^1$. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\frac{d \left(e^{-mx} f(x)\right)}{dx} &= -me^{-mx} f(x) + e^{-mx} f'(x) \\
&\leq 0.
\end{align*}
Then $e^{-mx} f(x) \leq 0$, and consequently $f(x)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Mean Value Theorem for Integrals to see that for some $c \in (0,x)$, you have
\begin{align*}
 f(x) = f(x) - f(0) = \int_0^x f'(t) \, dt = f'(c) \int_0^x m \, dt = mf'(c)(x-0) = Cx. 
\end{align*}
Considering what you already proved, $f \equiv 0$. You use the fact that $f \in C^1$ to justify $f'$ being integrable (i.e., to use FTOC).

In the post above by Gordon, I see why $e^{-mx} f(x) \leq C$, but I don't see why $C=0$.