# When does $g(x) > 0$ and $0 \le f'(x) \le g(x)f(x)$ imply that $f(x) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, functional-inequalities

When does $g(x) > 0$ and $0 \le f'(x) \le g(x)f(x)$ imply that $f(x) = 0$?

This question is inspired
by my urge to generalize
this question:

[Derivative bounded by the original function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438305/derivative-bounded-by-the-original-function)

I have some ideas on this,
but I want to see
the most general conditions on
$g(x)$
(and, perhaps,
$f(x)$)
that can make $f(x)$ be zero.

Comment: Hi Marty.  Assuming $g$ is integrable, have you considered analyzing the derivative of $e^{-\int g(x)\,dx}f(x)$?

Comment: Yup. That was my first thought. But I wanted to see if anything better was around.

Comment: You probably know https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grönwall's_inequality ? – Without an initial value $f(x_0)=0$ the conclusion $f(x)=0$ will probably not hold.

Comment: I may have known it, but I obviously didn't think of it when I wrote this question, because it answers the question. Thanks for the reminder.