# If $f \in \mathcal C^1[a,b]$, $f(a)=0$ and supose there is a $\lambda >0$ such that $|f'(x)| \leq \lambda |f(x)| \forall x \in (a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Does anyone know this theorem?
If $f \in \mathcal C^1[a,b]$, $f(a)=0$ and supose there is a $\lambda >0$ such that $|f'(x)| \leq \lambda |f(x)| \forall x \in (a,b)$. Does this imply that $f(x)=0$ in $[a,b]$?

My attempt: Yes.

First, notice that $f'(x)$ is continuous therefore if:
$|f'(x)| \leq \lambda |f(x)| \implies \lim_{x \rightarrow a}|f'(x)| \leq \lim_{x \rightarrow a} \lambda |f(x)| = 0 \iff f'(a) =0 $

Now take $y\in (a,b)$

there exists $c \in (a,y), f'(c) = \frac{f(y)}{y-a} \implies f(y) = f'(c)(y-a)$

$|f'(y)| \leq \lambda|f'(c)||y-a| \iff \lambda \geq \frac{|f'(y)|}{|f'(c)||y-a|}$

as $|f'(x)|$ is continuous in $[a,b]$ is admitis a minimum $m \geq 0$ in $[a,b]$

if $m=0$ $f(x)=0$. If not:

$\lambda \geq \frac m{|f'(c)||y-a|} \rightarrow \infty$

So $f(x) = 0$ indeed. Anyone knows the name of this theorem or if this proof is correct?

Comment: Why does $m=0$ imply $f(x)=0$ for all $x$? Also there's no reason $\frac{m}{|f'(c)||y-a|}\to\infty$. It's just a fixed number.

Comment: it goes to infinity when $y \rightarrow a$. $m=0$ implies $f'(x)=0$ in $[a,b]$ so $f(x)=f(a)=0$

Comment: By picking $m$ you fixed $y$, so there's no such thing as $y\to a$. $f'(x)=0$ for some $x\in[a,b]$ does not imply $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

Comment: I did not fix $y$. $m$ is the minimum in the interval $[a,b]$

Comment: And you meant $f'(y)=m$, for otherwise the inequality has no reason to hold.

Comment: ???????????????

Comment: This has been asked and answered quite often. You'll find more similar or identical questions with answers with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7Cf%27(x)%7C%20%5Cleq%20%5Clambda%20%7Cf(x)%7C%20%24&p=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the ways to prove your conclusion. Fix a positive number $\delta<\frac{1}{\lambda}$. Suppose that $|f|$ reaches its maximum on $[a,a+\delta]$ at $r\in[a,a+\delta]$. Then
$$ |f(r)|\leq f(a)+\lambda\int_a^r|f(x)|\,dx\leq\lambda\delta|f(r)|\,.$$
If $|f(r)|>0$, then we have $\lambda\delta\geq 1$, a contradiction. Hence $|f(x)|\leq|f(r)|=0$ for all $x\in[a,a+\delta]$. Now we have $f(a+\delta)=0$, we can replace $[a,a+\delta]$ by $[a+\delta,a+2\delta]$ in the previous argument, and so on.

Note that we did not make use of the condition $f'\in\mathcal{C}[a,b]$.

Comment: this is very nice! Specially since $f'$ does not need to be continuous. Do you know the name of this result?

Comment: @hellofriends I don't know if it has a name. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438305/derivative-bounded-by-the-original-function for similar results in differential inequality. I should also clarify that the continuity of $f'$ is there to make sure that $f'$ is integrable in the context of Riemann integration, so we can apply the fundamental theorem of calculus. In the context of Lebesgue integration, the integrability of $f'$ is guaranteed by boundedness.