# Derivative bounded by function

Tags: real-analysis

This question is a modification of the following question: [Derivative bounded by the original function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438305/derivative-bounded-by-the-original-function)

Let $f \in C^1[0, \infty]$ with $f(1)=0$, $f(x) \geq 0$. Suppose $\exists m >0$ s.t. $$f'(x)\leq m f(x) \qquad \forall x \geq 0$$
Must $f=0$?

(If you are curious why I'm asking this question, it's because this result was used for a differential equation uniqueness proof but I believe the result is not true).

Comment: The inequality tells you that (a.) $f$ is non-decreasing and (b.) $f$ is non-negative. Therefore, $f(0)=0$ and you're back to the linked question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry I meant to remove the condition $f'(x) \geq 0$, the condition should be $f(x) \geq 0$

Comment: Now if we use the answer in the linked question, we should get $f(x) = 0$ for $x \geq 1$, the question is if $f(x) = 0$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be equal to $(x-1)^2$ for $x \le 1$ and $0$ for $x>1$. It's differentiable and $\forall x \ge 0$ $f'(x) \le 0$, so $f'(x) \le f(x)$, so we can take $m = 1$. Also $f(x) \ge 0$ $\forall x \ge 0$.

Comment: since $f^\prime \le 0 $ for $x\le 1$ you can actually take any $m>0$